# Can a vehicle be stopped and driver ticketed for defective equipment in Texas when third stop lamp inoperable

Tags: criminal-law, texas, transportation

In Texas, I believe S 547.323. governs stoplamps in a vehicle. Subsection a states in part "... a motor vehicle ... shall be equipped with at least two stoplamps."

Is it not legal (can a driver be ticketed) to allow the third, high mounted stop lamp to become inoperative?

Similarly, if the third high mounted stop lamp still works and one of the other stop lamps are not working?

Thirdly, what if on some older model Thunderbirds from the 1980s, the brake lamp consists of one large wrap-around red plastic encased solid assembly with about 6 distint and seperate bulbs inside of it, and one of those goes out?

Just curious. At various times in my life in Texas I've been stopped for each of those instances and either ticketed or given a warning.

I don't think this is duplicate with [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17630/is-it-legal-to-pull-over-a-vehicle-in-oregon-for-having-a-tail-light-out-if-ther) because it involves tail lamps in Oregon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes because Texas adopted the Federal Motor Vehicle Safety Standard 571.108; TX Inspection Procedure Chapter 4, 04.20.28

Passenger cars manufactured 1986 – Newer: 3 stop lamps required
Light trucks/SUVs under 80” wide, manufactured 1994 – Newer: 3 stop lamps required
per DPS

Further Backed by Caselaw 
https://caselaw.findlaw.com/tx-court-of-appeals/1644657.html